# FTP management server

Tags: ftp, credentials

I am looking for a way to establish better FTP credential management.
The idea is that we have a lot of customer websites which all have their own FTP credentials. I would like to add those to some central server, so that employees don't need to access the credentials, instead they would connect to that local server, for example open the directory "customer X", and that folder would actually be connected to the remote FTP site.

This way, when central accounts (ActiveDirectory) are disabled, there is no need to worry whether the employee would still have knowledge of those external credentials.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are many commercial products out there that provide centralized management of FTP credentials.  One such that we use is made by [IPSWITCH call WS_FTP Pro](http://www.ipswitchft.com/).  They have a Site Manager feature that allows you to group all your FTP connections to various clients under profiles.