# Map FTP folder to folder on different FTP server

Tags: windows, networking, password-management, ftp

In my team we work a lot with FTP. We upload and download files from several different servers daily. Currently every member of the team manages access credentials to each FTP server locally on their own machine.

I am looking for a way to set up a central FTP server that we can connect to, and from there, navigate to folders that each represent one of the other FTP servers that we connect to daily. Something like this:

In-house central FTP server:

```
|- FolderA --> server A root folder
|- FolderB --> server B root folder
|- FolderC --> server C root folder
```

A setup like this, would mean that we can manage access credentials on the central FTP server, and team members would only need to have the access credentials to the central FTP server, and from there they could navigate to the other servers through these "virtual" folders.

We could potentially develop our own custom FTP server that just forward requests to the remote FTP servers, but i feel like something like this (or something similar) would already have been done. So I'm looking for pointers that could help us find software for Windows that could help us to simplify our current setup.

Thank you!

Similar (unanswered) question here: [FTP management server](https://superuser.com/questions/589539/ftp-management-server)

Comment: We never found a ready-made solution, so we ended up implementing our own FTP server.